# I need to pass an x-authorization token in the http get request in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to show an image on a drop-file in angular, and to do that I'm trying to return the file that is in my root directory C, with a get method in the [image]. But before it access the method that finds the file, the code passes through a SecurityInterceptor, and check if I have the x-authorization token, and I don't know how to pass it in this request.
Someone knows how to pass the token(x-authorization) in the link I used in [image] ?

```
  <drop-file (fileChanged)="getImgFile($event)" (fileRemoved)="fileRemoved()" [image]="'http://localhost:8081/users/107/photo_profile?t=1598626871263.png'" alt=""></drop-file>
```

Comment: Can you keep the image in src/assets folder?
If possible, that would be easiest way

Answer (score 0):

What I think is, you can use a separate async method to get the image from server. So when the async method calls the API, you can use your angular interceptor to attach the token.
When I say separate async method, it should usually come from a service.
And you can make a base64 data url from it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this http request interceptor.

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TokenService {
  intercept(request, next) {
        const token: string = sessionStorage.getItem('TOKEN');
        if (token) {
            request = request.clone({
              setHeaders: {
                Authorization: token
              }
            });
        }
        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```